# Configurable not showing thumbnail on product view page

Tags: configurable-product, thumbnail

[Here](http://dev.imok.ro/winter2/produse-noi/ski/skiuri/mystyle-exhale-cu-legaturi-fischer-v9.html) is an example (it should be showing 2 images).
I'm using Magento 1.9.2.

The site has 2000 products, and on the product view page at every single configurable product, only the main image is shown, no thumbnails. They just disappeared overnight.

Basically in the media.phtml file 'count($this->getGalleryImages())' returns 0 or null, that is why they are missing.

I have removed my template (used Ultimo-infortis), but same happening in RWD. 
Have tried to disable modules, but no avail.

I have uploaded some products through Magento import. Could that produce this error?

Please advise!
Thanks!